# How to iterate to each node to retrieve values in XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xmlnode

I have the following XML, stored in one column of one table:

```
<Selections> 
<TextSelection>
<words>
<index> 0 </index>
<text> hi </text>
</words>
</TextSelection>
<TextSelection>
<words>
<index> 1 </index>
<text> hello </text>
</words>
</TextSelection>
<id> 1 </id>
<followtext> yes </followtext>
<text> hi hello </text>
<response> greetings </response>

<TextSelection>
<words>
<index> 2 </index>
<text> dora </text>
</words>
</TextSelection>
<TextSelection>
<words>
<index> 3 </index>
<text> toy</text>
</words>
</TextSelection>
<id> 2 </id>
<followtext> yes </followtext>
<text> dora toy </text>
<response> like dora </response>
</Selections>
```

I need to retrieve text and response from above XML.

My query for retrieving values is:

```
select xml.value('(/Selections/TextSelection/words/text)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Selections, xml.value('(/Selections/TextSelection/words/response)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as Response from QResponse where rid = '20';
```

But it returns me Null value. How do I get these value ? And also I need to iterate next subsequent node to get that value ? How to accomplish this ?

And the output will be:

```
text          response
------------------------
hi hello      greetings
dora toy      like dora
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a brief review of your XML and the select statement, I suspect that your XPath is incorrect.
Perhaps try:

```
/Selections/TextSelection[1]/words[1]/text[1]
/Selections/response[1]
```

Also, the following link may be helpful:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/23/sqlauthority-news-guest-post-select-from-xml-jacob-sebastian/

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your trying to get a sibling.......but basically "following the item I am on".

and that leads to the:

"XQuery [value()]: The XQuery syntax 'following-sibling' is not supported."

:<

Here is an attempt....that will show the error.

```
declare @MyData XML

select @MyData = '

<Selections> 
    <id>1</id>
    <followtext> yes </followtext>
    <text> hi hello </text>
    <response> greetings </response>
    <id>2</id>
    <followtext> yes </followtext>
    <text> dora toy </text>
    <response> like dora </response>
</Selections>

'

    /*

text          response
------------------------
hi hello      greetings
dora toy      like dora
*/


SELECT T.c.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS [text]
, T.c.value('(../response)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS responseOne
, T.c.value('../following-sibling::response)', 'varchar(100)') AS responseTwo

FROM @MyData.nodes('(/Selections/text)') T(c)
```